# How to call test helper function from within integration tests?

Tags: testing, rust, integration-testing

I'm trying to figure out how to best organize my tests in Rust, and I'm running into the following problem. I have a test utility (`test_util`) that I define in a module and I would like to be able to use it from my unit tests as well as from my integration tests.

Definition of `test_util` in `src/lib.rs`:

```rust
#[cfg(test)]
pub mod test_util {
    pub fn test_helper() {}
}
```

I can access my helper function from my unit tests in another module, `src/some_module.rs`:

```rust
#[cfg(test)]
pub mod test {
    use crate::test_util::test_helper;

    #[test]
    fn test_test_helper() {
        test_helper();
    }
}
```

However, when I try to use the utility from my integration test, as in `tests/integration_test.rs`:

```rust
use my_project::test_util::test_helper;

#[test]
fn integration_test_test_helper() {
    test_helper();
}
```

I get the following compiler message:

```
8 | use my_project::test_util::test_helper;
  |                 ^^^^^^^^^ could not find `test_util` in `my_project`
```

Is there a good reason why it is not allowed to access test code from the project from within an integration test belonging to that *same* project? I get it that integration tests can only access the public parts of the code, but I think it would make sense to also allow access to the public parts of the unit test code. What would be a work around for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `test` feature is only enabled while tests are being run on *that* crate. Integration tests are run externally to the crate, so you cannot access anything that is gated on `test`.

In my company we have a convention to put shared test utilities in a public `test_utils` module at the top level of a crate. You *could* gate this module behind your own feature, say `integration_test`, which you always enable when running those tests, but we don't currently bother with that.